# Check if a list is only composed of values equal to 0 in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an array of return values from a PowerShell script and I would like to execute a command only if *all* items in the array are 0.  What I have is this:

```
- name: check if computer is running DC services
  raw: Get-Service -name {{item}}
  with_items:
    - "adws"
    - "kdc"
    - "netlogon"
  register: services
  # ignore_errors: yes
  failed_when: services.stderr and 'Cannot find any service with service name ' not in services.stderr
  changed_when: False

- name: debug services
  debug:
    var=services

- name: copy check_ad.exe to DCs
  win_copy: src=check_ad.exe dest='{{nagios_client_install_path}}\\check_ad.exe'
  tags: ['win-nagios-client']
  when: item.rc == 0
```

but this will run `copy check_ad.exe` if *any* of the services are running.  How can I change it to only run if *all* services are running?

Debug info is here:

```
ok: [server_name] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "services": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "failed_when_result": false, 
                "item": "adws", 
                "rc": 1, 
                "stderr": "Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'adws'.\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ Get-Service -name adws\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (adws:String) [Get-Service], Ser \r\n   viceCommandException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell. \r\n   Commands.GetServiceCommand\r\n \r\n\r\n", 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }, 
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "failed_when_result": false, 
                "item": "kdc", 
                "rc": 1, 
                "stderr": "Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'kdc'.\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ Get-Service -name kdc\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (kdc:String) [Get-Service], Serv \r\n   iceCommandException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell. \r\n   Commands.GetServiceCommand\r\n \r\n\r\n", 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }, 
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "failed_when_result": false, 
                "item": "netlogon", 
                "rc": 0, 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stdout": "\r\nStatus   Name               DisplayName                           \r\n------   ----               -----------                           \r\nRunning  Netlogon           netlogon                              \r\n\r\n\r\n", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "", 
                    "Status   Name               DisplayName                           ", 
                    "------   ----               -----------                           ", 
                    "Running  Netlogon           netlogon                              ", 
                    "", 
                    ""
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: "*this will run "copy check_ad.exe" if any of the services are running*" -- does it really? IMHO it should produce a syntax error in the last task.

Comment: @techraf — what syntax issue do you see?  I ran it many times without issue (aside from the one I mentioned of it not performing the intended action)

Comment: There is no loop in `copy check_ad.exe to DCs` task, so `item` is undefined and referring `item.rc` in the conditional should fail.

Comment: Oh haha, good point, I must have missed the last "with_items" line in my copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `rc` values are integers you can sum them up and compare the result to 0:

```
- name: copy check_ad.exe to DCs
  win_copy: src=check_ad.exe dest='{{nagios_client_install_path}}\\check_ad.exe'
  tags: ['win-nagios-client']
  when: services.results | map(attribute='rc') | sum == 0
```

---

A more general approach (not only for integers) would be to use a [`difference` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) removing all occurrences of `0` (from the resulting list of mapping `rc` as above) and checking the size of the remaining list.

If the original list contained other elements, the resulting value would be positive.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I thought about summing the rc fields but couldn't see a way to do that easily — thanks for the help with Jinja.